# Ibid in text appears where it should not

Tags: biblatex, citing

I use this package

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,sorting=ynt,dashed=false,uniquelist=false,maxnames=2,minnames=1,maxbibnames=99,backend=biber,sortcites=true,uniquename=false]{biblatex}
```

My bibliography and all the citations are fine, except for the case that ibid in a figure appears without reason. The reference cited in the figure is not anywhere mentioned in the text before or after. I also tried changing difference citations but ibid is still present.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Hrmm, that shouldn't be happening. I could not reproduce the behaviour you describe in a quick attempt to see what this is about (see https://gist.github.com/moewew/a062df7ec38c4eb10540046de6ed693d). I'm afraid I will only be able to look into this in more detail if you can add a short example document to your question that reproduces the issue (a so-called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/). I appreciate that it may (appear to be) difficult to produce an MWE for a question like this, but it is essential that we know what's going on.

Comment: I have many citations and in every other part, it works fine. only in this figure caption, it denies leaving even though I put different citations every time. I just decided to ''cheat'' and I wrote the name of the author and the date instead of \parencite{author}.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem cannot be reproduced in a simple example document (see above) and the OP seems to have found a workaround and is no longer interested in posting an example that reproduces the issue. Without an example document to go by, the problem cannot be diagnosed properly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.